# Finding the IP from the PID

Tags: process

Right now, I'm able to get the PID of a process from:

```
ps aux|grep processname
```

How can I get the Port no/IP of the process? There's lsof and fuser for Port to PID but is there another way to get the port from the PID?
I've already posted this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167537/finding-the-ip-from-the-pid) but thought that this forum would be more appropriate. Also i couldn't migrate the question by myself. Sorry for cross posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using netstat, you can use the -p option to include program name/PID. Something like this should work.

`netstat -a -p`